# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've Started learning c#, but this one problem, i can't seem to fix

I've tried changing stuff but i don't have enough knowledge to know what to do.

```
    public float raiseAtAltitude = 40;
    public float lowerAtAltitude = 40;

    private GearState m_State = GearState.Lowered;
    private Animator m_Animator;
    private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    private AeroplaneController m_Plane;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        m_Plane = GetComponent<AeroplaneController>();
        m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G)){
            raiseAtAltitude;
        }
        // set the parameter on the animator controller to trigger the appropriate animation
        m_Animator.SetInteger("GearState", (int) m_State);
    }
}
```

Assets\Standard Assets\Vehicles\Aircraft\Scripts\LandingGear.cs(42,5): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

it's the only Error.

Comment: Did you want to assign something here? `raiseAtAltitude;` I assume that's line 42.

Comment: `raiseAtAltitude;` is not a statement. All that line is is saying `40;` which is also not a statement. You have neither assigned a value to a variable, called a function, incremented or decremented a variable, `await`ed on something, or called `new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to make the object raise to an altitude on a key press?

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G)){
    raiseAtAltitude;
}
```

So here you are literally saying if key 'G' then 40; 
You must assign something to the variable or the variable to something like the RigidBody's transform.position. (x, y, z)

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G)){
    //something like this?
    m_Rigidbody.transform.position.y += raiseAtAltitude;
}
```

Comment: no, im trying to make the gears Close / Play the closing animation, i used every possible method like GearState.Lowered, GearState.Raised. None fix it :/

Comment: Okay, so for the compilation error, the line raiseAtAltitude is the problem though, if you comment it out the project compiles right?

As for the animation problem I recommend watching some tutorial videos and making sure you don't miss any steps and that everything is set up correctly in the editor. Ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PA51WUVRc4